# vocabulary related to phone put down or something else

Tags: vocabulary, telephone

What's the word in English when in a phone conversation, one party suddenly put down the reception without saying goodbye or completing the conversation, just because of a tense conversation?
Thank you

Answer (score 4):

***Hang up on*** (someone):

> To disconnect a phone call. ***The term is often used to mean to end the call in the middle of the conversation:***
>
> - Don't you dare hang up on me, I'm not done issuing my complaint! I can't hear you anymore, it must be a bad signal.

Comment: Interesting how we still say "hang up" now that  the earpiece no longer hangs on anything.